# C# How to terminate a click-event handler with another click-event

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a click-event handler to a button that forms an ssh connection. I want to terminate this function with another "cancel" button click.

However, when executing an event handler, "cancel" click event handler doesn't run while the first handler executing. I want to override the first handler with "cancel" handler.

```cs
private void button_sshconnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { /* some code to create ssh connection */ }

private void button_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { /* some code to terminate button_sshconnection_Click */ }
```

I tried a code-structure like the above code but as I said second function doesnt run while the first function running. If the structure is wrong, can someone tell me how to do this job.

Thanks in advance,

Onur

Comment: Are you looking for `Task` (to create ssh connection) and `CancellationToken` (to cancel the creation)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I am not sure what I am looking for, I am newbie in VisualStudio and c#. I am now trying `Task` and `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing *async* version of your routine, e.g.

```
   private CancellationTokenSource m_Cancellation;

   private async void button_sshconnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // if method is executing, do nothing. Alternative: cancel and start again   
     if (m_Cancellation != null)
       return;

     try { 
       using (m_Cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource()) {
         var token = m_Cancellation.Token;

         await Task.Run(() => {
           //TODO: implement your logic here, please, note that cancellation is cooperative
           // that's why you should check token.IsCancellationRequested

         }, token);
       }
     }
     finally {
       m_Cancellation = null;  
     }
   }

   private void button_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // If we can cancel, do it
     m_Cancellation?.Cancel();
   }
```

Comment: Nice idea with null check. But why are you nulling it in the final block only? Should not it be first Dispose then null? I guess when you null it the GC will dispose of it for you, is that correct?

Comment: @vsarunov: `using` which is a *syntax sugar* for `try {...} finally{m_Cancellation.Dispose()}` will dispose the instance first, then outer `finally` assign `null` to `m_Cancellation`

Comment: aha, yes. Noticed. This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: Good answer. Small nitpick: you should use [this prototype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) of Task.Run instead, so you can pass the cancellation token as the second parameter. This handles certain edge cases better.

Comment: @John Wu: thank you! `token` worth to be extracted (and tracked instead of `CancellationTokenSource`)

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko for your answer. The general structure is what I am looking for. However while function is running, it doesn't terminate when I pressed cancel button. It runs until it finishes itself.

Comment: @Onur: cancellation is *cooperative*: you should check `token.IsCancellationRequested` and `return`, `break` etc. execution your routine *manually*: `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;`